# How to insert en update with single submit button

Tags: php, mysql

I have this issue with code below.What am i trying to do is to with single submit button INSERT data in database and when its inserted if i need to change something i need to be able to perform a UPDATE on current day only to database on inserted row.But so far i am able to INSERT data but when i try to change something its insert just another row in db.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

    $TO_P20O = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'TO_P20O', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $TO_P21O = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'TO_P21O', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


        $to_ochtend = $conn->prepare(" SELECT * FROM tablePL WHERE created >= '".$huidige_dag."' order by id ");
        $to_ochtend->execute();
        $to_ochtend = $to_ochtend->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        $query = "INSERT INTO tablePL (id, TO_P20O, TO_P21O, created ) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, NOW())";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $TO_P20O, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $TO_P21O, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Data inserted successfully.');
        window.location.replace(\"$domain/succes\");
        </script>";

}

else {  

    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    $update_query = "UPDATE tablePL SET TO_P20O = ?, TO_P21O = ?, created = NOW() WHERE id = ? AND created >= ? LIMIT 1"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($update_query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $TO_P20O, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $TO_P21O, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $huidige_dag, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

Comment: Maybe do an [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) instead?

Comment: @PatrickQ Hi Patrick .. i did try that also but its stil insert new row instead to update a row.

Comment: You should show that attempt, as well as your table definition (the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE ... ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this in my code I simply add a hidden input in the form to pass a `$action` variable to the parse page.

```
echo '<form action="parse-content-types.php" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="returnto" name="returnto" value="manage-content-types.php">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="add">';
      include('form-content-types.php');

    echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col_12 center alpha omega">';
            echo '<input type="submit" class="button blue" value="Submit this Content Type">';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

echo '</form>';
```

This would be the parse-content-types.php:

```
<?php
    $level = '../../';
    include($level.'core/ini/start.php');

    $returnto = $_POST['returnto'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];

    $content_type_id = $_POST['content_type_id'];
    $content_type = $_POST['content_type'];
    $content_type_path = $_POST['content_type_path'];
    $content_type_desc = $_POST['content_type_desc'];

    if($action == 'add'){
        $insertq = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO content_types (
            content_type,
            content_type_path,
            content_type_desc
        )
        VALUES (?,?,?)');
        $insertq->execute(array(
            $content_type,
            $content_type_path,
            $content_type_desc
        ));

        $msg = 's|The item: '.$content_type.' has been inserted into the Content Types Database Table.';
    }
    elseif($action == 'edit'){
        $sql = 'update content_types set
            content_type_id=:content_type_id,
            content_type=:content_type,
            content_type_path=:content_type_path,
            content_type_desc=:content_type_desc
        where content_type_id=:THEID';

        $upd=$db->prepare($sql);
        $upd->bindParam(':content_type_id',$content_type_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $upd->bindParam(':content_type',$content_type,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $upd->bindParam(':content_type_path',$content_type_path,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $upd->bindParam(':content_type_desc',$content_type_desc,PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $upd->bindParam(':THEID',$content_type_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $upd->execute();

        $msg = 's|The item: '.$content_type.' has been updated in the Content Types Database Table.';
    }

    echo '<Script language="javascript">window.location="'.$returnto.'?msg='.$msg.'"</script>';
?>
```

Comment: you are more than welcome... notice that I include the form itself so the form can be edited from a single file.